# How to pickle a ssl.SSLContext object

Tags: python, multiprocessing, protocols, pickle

Python 3.5 on windows, try these:

```
import ssl, pickle, multiprocessing
context = ssl.create_default_context()
foo = pickle.dumps(context)
pickle.loads(foo)
```

Throws an exception:

```
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'protocol'
```

subclass of multiprocessing.Process throws the same exception:

```
class Foo(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.context = ssl.create_default_context()

    def run(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.start()
```

Comment: Why do you need to pickle an SSLContext object? You probably don't want to do that...

Comment: Because subclass of multiprocessing.Process throws the same exception. I had add the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
>>> import pickle, copyreg, ssl
>>>
>>> def save_sslcontext(obj):
...   return obj.__class__, (obj.protocol,)
... 
>>> copyreg.pickle(ssl.SSLContext, save_sslcontext)
>>> 
>>> context = ssl.create_default_context()
>>> foo = pickle.dumps(context)
>>> _foo = pickle.loads(foo)
>>> _foo
<ssl.SSLContext object at 0x1011812a8>
>>> _foo.protocol
2
>>>
```

Basically, a `SSLContext` needs a `protocol`, and for whatever reason, the `protocol` is not saved (e.g. it's not in a `__reduce__` method) when the instance is pickled.  If you need more state (i.e. other `args` and `kwds` from the `__init__` method), then you'll need to extend the return value from the `save_sslcontext` function above.  (Note, if you are in python 2.x, then the appropriate module is `copy_reg`).