# How to serialize a httplib SSL connection object in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, ssl, httplib

I am trying to send a httplib connection object over a zmq socket, but I am getting the following error `TypeError: can't pickle _ssl._SSLSocket objects`.

Now I thought this would have been the case as I am just experimenting at the moment, but does anyone know of a method to wrap or serialize the SSL object so that I can send it to other threads, over sockets?

An example use case:

```
#Script 1
import zmq
ctx = zmq.Context()
GLOBAL_SOCKET=ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
GLOBAL_SOCKET.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:2000')

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('site...')
GLOBAL_SOCKET.send_pyobj(conn)


#script 2
import zmq
ctx = zmq.Context()
GLOBAL_SOCKET=ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
GLOBAL_SOCKET.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:2000')
GLOBAL_SOCKET.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

#recv SSL object in response hopefully
conn_ = GLOBAL_SOCKET.recv_pyobj()

#work with the connection object in another thread
conn_.request('GET', ....)
conn_.request.getresponse()
```

Any help welcome.

Comment: Why can't you just open a new connection from the second process?

Comment: @Blender I knew this would come up: I had a longer question with more code explaining that I was trying to persist a single connection throughout the program, as I don't want to be making any new TCP handshakes. If you want I can elaborate in the question, but only if you think there might be a chance of a solultion?

Comment: @georgexsh what do you mean by "but one's child" ?

Comment: @ajsp you could send socket to another process with `sendmsg(2)` syscall, but IMO ZMQ works on top of socket API, so this is not possible.

Comment: @georgexsh could you shouw me a quick example of passing a httplib connection object over a socket georgexsh? That would actually answer the question. I have carved out a solution with ZMQ but there is a lot of work in it...hecne if I could just send the connection that would be better.

Comment: @ajsp socket cannot send over *socket* connection but with `sendmsg(2)` syscall within the same machine, you do want that?

Comment: @georgexsh That would answer the question, yes, 100%. Can you provide a working example below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a working example using `multiprocessing.Queue`:

```
import httplib
import ssl
import copy_reg
from multiprocessing.reduction import rebuild_socket, reduce_socket
from multiprocessing import Queue
import os


def save_sslcontext(obj):
    return obj.__class__, (obj.protocol,)

copy_reg.pickle(ssl.SSLSocket, reduce_socket, rebuild_socket)
copy_reg.pickle(ssl.SSLContext, save_sslcontext)


def parent():
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('www.baidu.com')
    conn.connect()
    queue.put(conn)
    os.wait()


def child():
    conn = queue.get()
    conn.request('GET', '/')
    r = conn.getresponse()
    print r.status


queue = Queue()
if 0 == os.fork():
    child()
else:
    parent()
```

Comment: Excellent, I see you have saved the actual protocol of the connection object, that's interesting, I will change the question tittle to reflect this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ajsp that is for pickle `SSLContext` object, [see this ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994158/how-to-pickle-a-ssl-sslcontext-object).